# Use AnsiColor in jenkins via powershell

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, ansi-colors

Any idea on how to use powershell to color my output on Jenkins ? I have already installed AnsiColor plugin on my Jenkins and I have set the job to use AnsiColor. The only problem is how to let my powershell output the color on Jenkins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I've never used it before so I figured I'd try it. Basically you just literally put an escape character (ASCII 27) followed by a left bracket `[` and then the codes, [as described on this page](http://bluesock.org/~willg/dev/ansi.html), directly into the string.

To make this easier, I wrote a function that formats the string:

```
function Format-AnsiColor {
[CmdletBinding()]
[OutputType([String])]
param(
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory = $true,
        ValueFromPipeline = $true
    )]
    [AllowEmptyString()]
    [String]
    $Message ,

    [Parameter()]
    [ValidateSet(
         'normal display'
        ,'bold'
        ,'underline (mono only)'
        ,'blink on'
        ,'reverse video on'
        ,'nondisplayed (invisible)'
    )]
    [Alias('attribute')]
    [String]
    $Style ,

    [Parameter()]
    [ValidateSet(
         'black'
        ,'red'
        ,'green'
        ,'yellow'
        ,'blue'
        ,'magenta'
        ,'cyan'
        ,'white'
    )]
    [Alias('fg')]
    [String]
    $ForegroundColor ,

    [Parameter()]
    [ValidateSet(
         'black'
        ,'red'
        ,'green'
        ,'yellow'
        ,'blue'
        ,'magenta'
        ,'cyan'
        ,'white'
    )]
    [Alias('bg')]
    [String]
    $BackgroundColor
)

    Begin {
        $e = [char]27

        $attrib = @{
            'normal display' = 0
            'bold' = 1
            'underline (mono only)' = 4
            'blink on' = 5
            'reverse video on' = 7
            'nondisplayed (invisible)' = 8
        }

        $fore = @{
            black = 30
            red = 31
            green = 32
            yellow = 33
            blue = 34
            magenta = 35
            cyan = 36
            white = 37
        }

        $back = @{
            black = 40
            red = 41
            green = 42
            yellow = 43
            blue = 44
            magenta = 45
            cyan = 46
            white = 47
        }
    }

    Process {
        $formats = @()
        if ($Style) {
            $formats += $attrib[$Style]
        }
        if ($ForegroundColor) {
            $formats += $fore[$ForegroundColor]
        }
        if ($BackgroundColor) {
            $formats += $back[$BackgroundColor]
        }
        if ($formats) {
            $formatter = "$e[$($formats -join ';')m"
        }

       "$formatter$_"
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Format-AnsiColor -Message 'Hey there' -Style Bold -ForegroundColor Red

'Hello' | Format-AnsiColor -BackgroundColor Green

'One','Two','Three' | Format-AnsiColor -Style 'normal display' -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Black
```

Remember that you have to turn off the sequence (by that I mean set the style and colors back to whatever it was before) if you don't want it anymore.

Comment: This is so beautiful :) it works but do I need to set the color back to white so my jenkin's page does not preserve the last color I used ?

Comment: @fazlook1 yes you do. The sequences set the color and don't set it back, so you have to do that yourself. The function could maybe be written to better account for that.

Comment: I will do my best to edit it myself. Thank you so much, you made my day. Oh wait......now if I run PS from it is own IDE , I get back these : [42mHello
[0;37;43mOne
[0;37;43mTwo
[0;37;43mThree , how do I fix that ?

Comment: @fazlook1 well.. that's what the function does. If there's nothing to interpret the sequences you'll see them. You can assign the output of this function to a string, so you can use your own logic to determine whether or not to use this function, then send your (formatted or not) string to `Write-Host` or to the pipeline.. that's all I can do for now.

Comment: How could I make this function more generic ? I just want to say something like that: Format-AnsiColor "my message is here" and that by default would be colored RED. Is it possible ?

Comment: @fazlook1 you can leave the function alone and [use `$PSDefaultParameterValues`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847819.aspx), or you can just assign a default value for the foreground color to red: `$ForegroundColor = 'red' ,` in the parameter declaration.

Answer (score 3):

I use lot of long powershell in my Jenkin, color is essential !
I overwrite the native Write-Host in profile.ps1 of my Jenkins User. and now all my local script is colorized on Jenkins

```
function Write-Host {
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
            Wrapper for Write-Host, adds ANSI SGR codes based on -foregroundColor and -backgroundColor
        .DESCRIPTION
            Renplace le Write-host standard, pour une compatibilité avec les sorties linux (JENKINS)
        .PARAMETER object
            Liste de String qui seront regroupe et affichée en couleur
        .PARAMETER foregroundColor
            Couleur du texte
        .PARAMETER backgroundColor
            Couleur de fond
        .PARAMETER nonewline
            si pas de retour a la ligne
        .NOTES
             Alban LOPEZ 2018
             alban.lopez@gmail.com
             http://git/PowerTech/
    #>
    param(
        $object,
        [ConsoleColor]$foregroundColor,
        [ConsoleColor]$backgroundColor,
        [switch]$nonewline
    )
        if (!(Get-Command Write-HostOriginal -ea 0).name){ # doit etre embarque (pour les scriptblock)
            $global:ConsoleOutput = ''
            $metaData = New-Object System.Management.Automation.CommandMetaData (Get-Command 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Host')
            Invoke-Expression "function Global:Write-HostOriginal { $([System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::create($metaData)) }"
        }

        # https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolecolor(v=vs.110).aspx
        # Converted to closest ANSI SGR equivalent
        $AnsiColor = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{ # doit etre embarque (pour les scriptblock)
            ForeGround = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
                Black = 30
                Red = 91
                DarkRed = 31
                Green = 92
                DarkGreen = 32
                Yellow = 93
                DarkYellow = 33
                Blue = 94
                DarkBlue = 34
                Magenta = 95
                DarkMagenta = 35
                Cyan = 96
                DarkCyan = 36
                White = 97
                Gray = 37
                DarkGray = 90
            }
            BackGround = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
                Black = 40
                White = 107
                Red = 101
                DarkRed = 41
                Green = 102
                DarkGreen = 42
                Yellow = 103
                DarkYellow = 43
                Blue = 104
                DarkBlue = 44
                Magenta = 105
                DarkMagenta = 45
                Cyan = 106
                DarkCyan = 46
                Gray = 47
                DarkGray = 100
            }
            style = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
                RESET = 0
                BOLD_ON = 1
                ITALIC_ON = 3
                UNDERLINE_ON = 4
                BLINK_ON = 5
                REVERSE_ON = 7
                # BOLD_OFF = 22
                # ITALIC_OFF = 23
                # UDERLINE_OFF = 24
                # BLINK_OFF = 25
                # REVERSE_OFF = 27
            }
        }
        function Colorize-Text {
            <#
                .SYNOPSIS
                    Adds ANSI SGR codes to a string.
                .DESCRIPTION
                    Adds ANSI SGR codes to a string.
                .PARAMETER text
                    Text to be transformed.
                .PARAMETER ansiSgrCode
                    ANSI SGR number to insert.
                    See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code for details
                    Or use the [AnsiColor] enum.

                    Also accepts an array of SGR numbers, and will apply all of them.
                .NOTES
                    Designed to play nicely with https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AnsiColor+Plugin
                .EXAMPLE
                    Colorize-Text 'toto' 7,93,101
            #>
            param(
                $object,
                [int[]]$ansiCodes #https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#graphics
            )
            return "$([char]27)[$($ansiCodes -join(';'))m$object$([char]27)[0m"
        }

    $ansiCodes = @()

    if($style){
        $ansiCodes += $AnsiColor.style.$style
    }
    if($foregroundColor){
        $ansiCodes += $AnsiColor.ForeGround.$foregroundColor
    }
    if($backgroundColor) {
        $ansiCodes += $AnsiColor.BackGround.$backgroundColor
    }

    # Write-HostOriginal (Colorize-Text $object -ansiCodes $ansiCodes ) -nonewline # | Out-Host
    # (Colorize-Text $object -ansiCodes $ansiCodes ) | Out-Host
    # [Console]::Write( (Colorize-Text $object -ansiCodes $ansiCodes ) )
    if($foregroundColor -and $backgroundColor){
        # Write-HostOriginal (Colorize-Text $object -ansiCodes $ansiCodes ) -ForegroundColor $foregroundColor -BackgroundColor $backgroundColor -nonewline # | Out-Host
        $global:ConsoleOutput += (Colorize-Text $object -ansiCodes $ansiCodes )
    } elseif($foregroundColor){
        # Write-HostOriginal (Colorize-Text $object -ansiCodes $ansiCodes ) -ForegroundColor $foregroundColor -nonewline # | Out-Host
        $global:ConsoleOutput += (Colorize-Text $object -ansiCodes $ansiCodes )
    } elseif($backgroundColor){
        # Write-HostOriginal (Colorize-Text $object -ansiCodes $ansiCodes ) -BackgroundColor $backgroundColor -nonewline # | Out-Host
        $global:ConsoleOutput += (Colorize-Text $object -ansiCodes $ansiCodes )
    } else {
        # Write-HostOriginal $object -nonewline # | Out-Host
        $global:ConsoleOutput += $object
    }
    if (!$nonewline) {
        Write-HostOriginal $global:ConsoleOutput # -NoNewline
        $global:ConsoleOutput = ''
        # Write-HostOriginal '$!' -fore magenta 
    }
}
```

This code is compatible to ScriptBlock in thread and remote usage (Start-Job, Invoke-command)

Comment: HI there! Thanks for this nice script! I don't understand how to use this script in Jenkins powershell shell :)  "in profile.ps1 of my Jenkins User." How could i achieve that? THanks!

Comment: Hi there! It's not working with: <code>Invoke-Command -ComputerName $nodeName -Authentication NegotiateWithImplicitCredential -ScriptBlock ${function:Set-WinServiceQC}<code>

Answer (score 2):

Drop-in [Write-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) replacement that uses [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#3/4_bit) to render colors.
Allows for colorized output in CI systems.

- [Source](https://github.com/beatcracker/Powershell-Misc/blob/master/Write-Host.ps1)

```
.Synopsis
    Write-Host but with ANSI colors!

.Description
    Drop-in Write-Host replacement that uses ANSI escape codes to render colors.
    Allows for colorized output in CI systems.

.Parameter Object
    Objects to display in the host.

.Parameter ForegroundColor
    Specifies the text color. There is no default.

.Parameter BackgroundColor
    Specifies the background color. There is no default.

.Parameter Separator
    Specifies a separator string to insert between objects displayed by the host.

.Parameter NoNewline
    The string representations of the input objects are concatenated to form the output.
    No spaces or newlines are inserted between the output strings.
    No newline is added after the last output string.

.Example
    Write-Host 'Double rainbow!' -ForegroundColor Magenta -BackgroundColor Yellow

.Notes
    Author : beatcracker (https://github.com/beatcracker)
    License: MS-PL (https://opensource.org/licenses/MS-PL)
    Source : https://github.com/beatcracker/Powershell-Misc
#>
function Write-Host {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [Alias('Msg', 'Message')]
        [System.Object[]]$Object,
        [System.Object]$Separator,
        [System.ConsoleColor]$ForegroundColor,
        [System.ConsoleColor]$BackgroundColor,
        [switch]$NoNewline
    )

    Begin {
        # Map ConsoleColor enum values to ANSI colors
        # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#3/4_bit
        $AnsiColor = @(
            30, 34, 32, 36, 31, 35, 33, 37, 90, 94, 92, 96, 91, 95, 93, 97
        )
        # PS < 6.0 doesn't have `e escape character
        $Esc = [char]27
        $AnsiTemplate = "$Esc[{0}m{1}$Esc[{2}m"
    }

    Process {
        # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters#escape-e
        # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/wmf/whats-new/console-improvements#vt100-support
        if ($Host.UI.SupportsVirtualTerminal) {
            $Method = if ($NoNewline) { 'Write' } else { 'WriteLine' }
            $Output = if ($Separator) { $Object -join $Separator } else { "$Object" }

            # Splitting by regex ensures that this will work on files from Windows/Linux/macOS
            # Get-Content .\Foobar.txt -Raw | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red
            foreach ($item in $Output -split '\r\n|\r|\n') {
                if ("$BackgroundColor") {
                    $item = $AnsiTemplate -f ($AnsiColor[$BackgroundColor.value__] + 10), $item, 49
                }
                if ("$ForegroundColor") {
                    $item = $AnsiTemplate -f $AnsiColor[$ForegroundColor.value__], $item, 39
                }

                [System.Console]::$Method($item)
            }
        }
        else {
            Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Host @PSBoundParameters
        }
    }
}
```