# jenkins PowerShell customize colour console output

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm new to Jenkins. I have installed the "Ansi colour Plugin"
I have made a powershell script which is checking the diskspace. 
When there is enough space than I write to the console "Enough diskspace", when it is less to I want to write "Not enough diskspace".
This working fine.

But now I want when the text is written to the jenkins console:

- green if there is "Enough diskspace"
- red if there is "Not enough diskspace"

At the Jenkins configuration I see the Ansi colour plugin with a colour map for "xterm", "css" and one or two others.

I'm looking for a simple example how to colouring/customizing console ouput when using PowerShell.

Or is this not possible? Or can I have made configuration mistake(s)?

Nico

Comment: This seems to be explained in the docs for this plugin? https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AnsiColor+Plugin

Comment: I have been there, but there is in my opinion nothing specified or explained. Certainly not for powershell specific.

Comment: It would have to be in Groovy not powershell. It's a pipeline plugin. Reading the docs it seems you just wrap what ever groovy command you want in a colour in `ansiColor('colour')`. Have you tried this? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a new write-host function which does the ansi color conversion for you.  Then you just need to save it as a profile wherever you are running your PS code.  See Alban's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50984563/10377072